# sphinxtrain - Configuration not defined

Tags: speech-recognition, sphinx4

I am trying to train an acoustic model for CMUSphinx following the tutorial [here](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialam/).

So when i am training with the command `sphinxtrain run`, I am getting the following problems:

```
Sphinxtrain path: /usr/local/lib/sphinxtrain
Sphinxtrain binaries path: /usr/local/libexec/sphinxtrain
Running the training
Configuration (e.g. etc/sphinx_train.cfg) not defined
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib/sphinxtrain/scripts/000.comp_feat/slave_feat.pl line 51.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/lib/sphinxtrain/scripts/000.comp_feat/slave_feat.pl line 51.
```

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VK4AzbYwRqOZ0zPxheN1JMYqpSltQU9D/view?usp=sharing) is the file "sphinx_train.cfg"

Also no log file is created.

I am using Linux and I have downloaded sphinx [here](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/download/).

How to solve this problem?

Comment: According to the [tutorial](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialam/) you should run `sphinxtrain -t an4 setup` first

Comment: @HåkonHægland, I have already done that except that I have replaced an4 with "other" which is my task name.

Comment: Ok, next the tutorial says you should `cd an4` and then run `sphinxtrain run`. Did you do that also?

Comment: Yes, i did that.

Comment: *"Configuration (e.g. etc/sphinx_train.cfg) not defined"* As I understand, the command `sphinxtrain -t an4 setup` should create a directory `etc` (inside the `an4` folder). Do you have that directory?

Comment: Not all directory mentioned in the tutorial was created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by specifying the full path of `sphinx_train.cfg`.

This is the line I edit in slave_feat.pl at line 50.

```
use SphinxTrain::Config cfg => '/home/ridwan/sphinx/other/etc/sphinx_train.cfg';
```

I did this for every file where the compilation failed:

> Configuration (e.g. etc/sphinx_train.cfg) not defined